# Minimal surface with radially symmetrical function

Tags: riemannian-geometry, surfaces, calculus-of-variations, minimal-surfaces

The following image is from the book "Regularity Theory for Mean Curvature Flow", by Ecker.

[image]

I consider the plateau problem, whose goal is to solve minimal surface given fixed boundary values.

In the case of radially symmetrical case, I wonder what shape the minimal surface is if

```
the boundary is $u(x)=f(r)=b$ when $r$ is the largest radius.
```

---

For example, if I implement this by using gradient descent, I set the following as initial guess:

```
the boundary value: $f(r_{end})=1$ and other values $f(r)=0$,
```

what shape the minimal surface should it be?

The following figure is an intermediate result of my implementation. The x axis denotes 'r' (from 0 to 1) and the y axis denotes $f(r)$. Does this result make sense?

[image]

Comment: The only minimal surfaces of revolution are the [Catenoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenoid) and the plane, so you are going to get one of those - if anything, sometimes there is no solution at all. Your question is unclear, though: what is confusing in part 1? What do you mean by "other values" in part 2.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to implement this. I am sorry that the question 2 is just related to my implementation. Because I use gradient descent, the question is related to initial guess. I have removed the question 2.